# Attempting to open Xamarin layout designer freezes Visual Studio with no errors

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

Before I get into the question: I am using visual studio 2015 Community with Xamarin. I have tried the following to rectify this problem:

- Complete VS uninstall and reinstall (along with all components of Xamarin and Android SDK.)
- Rolled back various updates to Xamarin (including the most recent one)
- Ran repair install on visual studio, c++ 2015 redists (x86, and x64)
- Scoured Xamarin forums and Xamarin bugzilla for similar issues. While I found some that dealt with similar issues with the designer. None of them described the exact problem I'm having.

**Ok, now that's out of the way, here's my issue:**

I was happily working my way through a tutorial on Xamarin.android and things were going great. I was also concurrently building my own simple app to practice my new skill and make it meaningful.

Somewhere along the line either the Android SDK manager or the Xamarin updater wanted me to update something so I went ahead and did it. This started giving me some strange behavior, plus my VS Community install hasn't seen much maintenance lately, so I decided to do a full wipe and reinstall. This took quite a long time between Visual Studio and all the Xamarin and Android tools and updates.

**Once I was done I started working again, however any time I try to open a layout (.axml) file in the designer, visual studio totally freezes. If I'm fast I can click to the code interface, but it still locks up. 
I can add new layouts to the solution, but the project won't see them (they exist in the folder however, and can be opened with notepad++) if I include them, and then try to open them, the same thing happens. 
By 'freezes', I can't click anything in VS, even to close the window, I have to force close it from task manager. This is also strange as task manager doesn't show the program as locked up, only using a minimal amount of ram and cpu (as if it was idling normally).**

If I let it sit locked up long enough, Windows will prompt me to run VS from a devenv (not exactly sure what this means). When I do this and reproduce the problem (attempt to open a layout file) I get a long log of unintelligible errors. The only hints I found were some references to missing c++ libraries, which doesn't add up as I have run the repair tool for my redistributables several times now.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? And if so how should I fix it? It this totally prevents me from doing anything with Xamarin and is a big turn-off to the product. (this isn't the first breaking bug I've encountered)

Here is all my version info:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01038
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA850 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA850 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA850 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   00322-20000-00000-AA850 Windows Phone
>   SDK 8.0 - ENU
>
> Add New File   3.5 The fastest and easiest way to add new files to any
>   project - including files that start with a dot
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11107.0 ASP.NET and Web
>   Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.8 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Dummy Text Generator   1.2.12 Easily insert dummy text into the editor
>   in Visual Studio. Lorem Ipsum and other vocabularies are supported.
>
> GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0 A Visual Studio Extension that brings the
>   GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit
>
> Open Command Line   2.1.177 Opens a command line at the root of the
>   project. Support for all consoles such as CMD, PowerShell, Bash etc.
>   Provides syntax highlighting, Intellisense and execution of .cmd and
>   .bat files.
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox   4.6.0 SQL Server Compact &
>   SQLite Toolbox adds scripting, import, export, rename, query execution
>   and much more to SQL Server Compact & SQLite Data Connections.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   1.8.36.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova   Update 10 Visual Studio Tools
>   for Apache Cordova
>
> Web Compiler   1.11.319 Compiler for LESS, Sass and CoffeeScript files
>
> Web Essentials 2015.3   3.0.235 Adds many useful features to Visual
>   Studio for web developers. Requires Visual Studio 2015
>
> Xamarin   4.1.2.18 (fcbe082) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android   6.1.2.21 (1cf254d) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for "Xamarin.Android".
>
> Xamarin.iOS   9.8.2.22 (f37444a) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Could you provide your version info from Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info [button]? Does this also happen with a new project from template? If you have not already done so, please install JDK 1.8 [required for API 24+](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/) and check that the correct locations for JDK, SDK, NDK are pointed to under Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings.

Comment: Yes, it happens on new projects as well when adding a template to existing ones (Add New..-> Android Layout). I do have JDK 1.8 and all are pointed at the correct location. I'll add version info in the main post.

Comment: It builds up memory or something from what I can gather. Every now and then, close your VS completely, reopen, then it should work fine again for a while